# Анализ текста сайта в тегах body

Tags: python, python-3.x

После парсинга,нужно найти все строки, содержащиеся между тегами `и` и найти те строки, которые встречаются чаще всего и вывести их в алфавитном порядке, разделяя пробелами?

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
```

html=urlopen("https://stepik.org/media/attachments/lesson/209719/2.html").read().decode('utf-8')

пробовал делать так:

```
s = str(html)            print(s.count("<code>(.*?)</code>"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предлагаю вот такой вариант:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

#Читаем страницу
url = "https://stepik.org/media/attachments/lesson/209719/2.html"
page = requests.get(url)

#парсим тег
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "html.parser")
tags = soup.findAll('code')

#создаем словарь: ключ - содержимое тега, значение - количество повторений
dd={}

for x in tags:
    if x.text not in dd.keys():
        dd[x.text]=1
    else:
        dd[x.text]+=1

#максимум количества повторений
zmax=max(dd.values())

#вывод строк с максимальным количеством повторений
for k in dd.keys():
    if dd[k]==zmax:
    print(k,end=" ")
```

Comment: else except finally 
Process finished with exit code 0  # выдает такой результат

Comment: А что вы ожидаете? Выдает самые часто вчтречающиеся строки и успешно завершает работу. Вы можете вывести dd на экран посмотреть.